# Confirmation did not match DATABASE_NAME. Aborted

Tags: php, database, postgresql, heroku, upgrade

Heroku gives me this error

```
Confirmation did not match NEW_DATABASE_NAME. Aborted.
```

when I try to upgrade from hobby-dev to hobby-basic in the step of copying the database

```
 heroku pg:copy OLD_DATABASE_URL NEW_DATABASE_URL --app APP_NAME
```

Anyone Can Figure the problem ?

Comment: I just have to ask...  have you changed OLD_DATABASE_URL and NEW_DATABASE_URL to the correct url's?

Comment: yes I put the full url , I then get 

    !    To proceed, type "NEW DATABASE NAME" or re-run this command with --confirm NEW DATABASE NAME

I tried to type the name put it doesn't work , I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you probably got was:

```
>
> !    Confirmation did not match <APP NAME>. Aborted.
```

It's app name, not addon name here.

Also, you do not have to put the full URL, the colors and DATABASE_URL are the correct way to do it, eg:

```
> heroku pg:copy DATABASE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL
```